# Adding symbols for vector layer

Tags: qgis, symbology, import, library

I'm trying to figure out how to add some public safety symbols to QGIS (3.34.2) like a simple and clean symbol for a firehouse location.

Is there an existing library of symbols that can be turned on or imported?

Comment: Did you have a look at the QGIS Resource Sharing plugin or at the QGIS Hub plugin ? Or simply use SVG symbol

Comment: You appear to have two logins. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: You can use the QGIS Style Manager to import or export items.  You can search the web for symbols like SVG or fonts and download them to your computer.  SVG can just be added to your SVG folder which in an OSGeo4W install is in the OSGeo4W folder.  Downloaded fonts could go into your Windows fonts and then be imported for use in QGIS via Style Manager.